# Comparing every values columns and rows in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of different sizes and I would like to use a comparison for all values in four different columns, (two sets of two)

Essentially I would like to see where df1['A'] == df2['A'] & where df1['B'] == df2['B'] and return df1['C']'s value plus df2['C']'s values

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 3], "B": [2, 5, 4, 7, 5], "C": [1, 2, 8, 0, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 3, 2, 4, 8], "B": [5, 5, 4, 9, 1], "C": [1, 3, 3, 4, 6]})


df1:
  A B C
0 1 2 1
1 2 5 2
2 3 4 8
3 4 7 0
4 3 5 0
...

df2:
  A B C
0 1 5 1
1 3 4 3
2 2 5 4
3 4 9 4
5 8 1 6
...

in: df1['A'] == df2['A'] & where df1['B'] == df2['B']
       df1['D'] = df1['C'] + df2['C'] 

out: df1:
  A B C D
0 1 2 1 nan
1 2 5 2 6
2 3 4 8 11
3 4 7 0 nan
4 3 5 0 nan
```

My actual dataframes are much larger (120000ish rows of data with values for both 'A' columns range from 1 to 700 and 'B' from 1 to 300) so I know it might be a longer process.

Comment: I also meant to mention that the numbers in both column 'A' 's repeat several times, think of it more like two sets of a data from a grided plane, where there is a column and a row number dedicated for each cell, and I need to do math where the two cells are equal (the two rows are equal and the two columns are equal) in this case I named them 'A' and 'B' respectably, but that's to avoid confusion, which I didn't do too good a job of I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could first merge the two dataframes

```
In [145]: dff = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'], how='left')

In [146]: dff
Out[146]:
   A  B  C_x  C_y
0  1  2    1  NaN
1  2  5    2    4
2  3  4    8    3
3  4  7    0  NaN
```

Then, take row-wise sum on `C_-{like}` columns, where null values are not present, then fill NaN with zero.

```
In [147]: dff['C'] = dff.filter(regex='C_').sum(skipna=False, axis=1).fillna(0)

In [148]: dff
Out[148]:
   A  B  C_x  C_y   C
0  1  2    1  NaN   0
1  2  5    2    4   6
2  3  4    8    3  11
3  4  7    0  NaN   0
```

And, you can drop/pick required columns.

Comment: appreciate the help, I see what you're saying to do, but what I forgot to mention was that in both df's column 'A' and column 'B' there are a lot of repeating numbers from 1-700 for 'A' and 1-300 for 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` the two DataFrames on columns A and B.  Since you want to keep all values from `df1`, do a left merge of `df1` and `df2`.  The merged column C from `df2` will be null wherever A and B don't match. After the merge, it's just a matter of renaming the merged column and doing a sum.

```
# Do a left merge, keeping df1 column names unchanged.
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['A', 'B'], suffixes=('', '_2'))

# Add the two columns, fill locations that don't match with zero, and rename.
df1['C_2'] = df1['C_2'].add(df1['C']).fillna(0)
df1.rename(columns={'C_2': 'D'}, inplace=True)
```